# Doesn't show "Update" button in playstore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-version

Here I am developing Android app with android studio. I turned my google account into a google developer account and then published my app in the play store after signing that app within my computer. After a month I published an update for that app with the same package name. I also upgraded the "Version Name" & "Version Code". I checked the the situation by using a phone which has the initial release of the app, but after I released the update the specific page of that app in play store doesn't show an update button ("open"button is there).

How can I correct this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your phone with the "initial release" of the app didn't install it from the Play store, then the Play store won't update it. I suspect this will be your problem.

The Play store will only update apps for which it did the initial install (to avoid treading on the toes of app developers during development or other app stores).

The way it checks for "Did the Play store install this" is "Does the signature of the app match the signature in the Play store" and "does the user on the phone have a record of install from the Play store on their account on any device".

Comment: Hi Nick, I spent a fair amount of time trying to make this work. I signed the two apps with exactly the same signature, so that should not be a problem, but in reference to your second check, do you have any documentation on this? I wasn't aware of it at all.

Comment: In all the years I have been developing apps I never saw this behavior before.  Of course it happens though the moment I am show casing an app to someone.  App pops up a message (as designed) to say a newer version of the app is available, then it goes to the app store and only shows the `open` button that simply rerouted back to the already open app.  After 3 attempts I looked like a fool - show casing an app that I am having to explain why its not working.  Ugh!

Answer (score 1):

After updating an app on play store it can take several hours to be available on play store. Just wait for couple of hours.

Comment: Thank you for replying Ahmad. But its had been a month that I published the app. But still the same

Comment: Is there ant error on playstore or some message? Or may be it is automatically updated.

Comment: @lasith.chandupa did u solve it? i face same problem

Comment: Google must have sent you email if something is wrong. Usually it only takes few hours

Comment: @JaiGtz nop dear still on it

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you have to make sure the following three points are in place:

You are installing exactly the same variant from android studio compared to the one you published on google play store.
The app you installed from android studio has a lower "version code"
You are using exactly the same signing key.
Most likely the third point is what is stopping this from working. The problem is that if you are using app bundle as publishing format, that apk is not created yet when you upload the bundle and it will only be create and SIGNED at a later the stage, when the app is about to be distributed on a specific device.

Unfortunately, there is a chance, like in my case, that the signature still will not match perfectly even if you used exactly the same key to sign the app, reason being that if you have singed up for Google Play Store signing, google will add some metadata: "It does however insert a minuscule amount of metadata that helps with verifying the source and integrity of the distribution. This metadata comes in two flavors: For all apps uploaded to Google Play, Play has been adding security metadata after the signing block to enable features such as authorized P2P app sharing. We announced this originally in a blog post in 2017. For apps uploaded as app bundles, we will improve this security by introducing what is called a source stamp. This source metadata is inserted into the app’s manifest by bundletool. When the APK is generated on Play’s server, it’s also signed with a Google key in addition to your app signing key."

I yet have to solve this issue unfortunately